# How to get size from swf file?

Tags: php, object, flash, size, scale

I have dynamic pages with swf file inside 'object' tag, but swf files have not identical size.
So for more crossbrowsing method i need to set size attributes for 'object'....here is the problem: i don`t know how to get size from swf and transmit it to php. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$media  = "media.swf";
$dem    = getimagesize($media);
$height = $dem[1];
$width  = $dem[0];
```

[PHP's `getimagesize()`  documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)